# Python statsmodels: Difference between sm.GLM(family = NegativeBinomial) vs sm.NegativeBinomial

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a regression model using statsmodels.  Here's my code:

What is the difference between:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.GLM(Y, X, family= sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit()
```

and

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.NegativeBinomial(Y, X).fit()
```

For whatever reason, the first piece of code works, but the second gives me the following error:

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check whether your `X` has full rank. `sm.NegativeBinomial` doesn't work with singular `X`. If `X` has full rank, then it could still get a Singular matrix during optimization. In that case you could try a different optimizer, `e.g. fit(method='bfgs')`

Comment: one difference is that GLM takes the shape parameter of NegativeBinomial as given, in order to be in the exponential family of distributions.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the second example is a more general case of the first.  Is there any way to do regularization using sm.GLM...?

Comment: Just to make sure -- in order to be in the exponential family of distributions, r (number of failures) =1, right?